# Aggregate yearly sum of selected months of a time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, zoo

I have a time series of monthly data over multiple years. Now I'd like to calculated different indices for each year like e.g. (i) the annual sum and (ii) the sum of specific months (July and August). I want to use the `aggregate` function in `R` and the `zoo`-package.

Calculating the yearly sum was not the problem...

```
# Test dataset
z_test <-  as.zoo(ts(rnorm(200), start=c(1922,1), frequency=12))

# Yearly sum
as.year <- function(x) as.numeric(floor(as.yearmon(x)))
yearsum <- as.ts(aggregate(z_test, as.year, sum))
```

..however, what is the best way to return the sum of specific months using aggregate? For example I would like to have the sum of July and August for each year (similar shape as `yearsum`)

```
JulAug_sum <-?
```

Comment: Johannes, does this solution work for you?

Comment: Note that `as.year <- function(x) as.integer(as.yearmon(x))` would also work.  `ts_test` is defined as a zoo object but then it is coerced to zoo again in the aggregate statement which is redundant. It might be better to call it `z_test` to emphasize that it is a zoo object and not a ts object.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
library(zoo)

# Test dataset
ts_test <-  as.zoo(ts(rnorm(200), start=c(1922,1), frequency=12))

# Yearly sum
as.year <- function(x) as.numeric(floor(as.yearmon(x)))
yearsum <- as.ts(aggregate(as.zoo(ts_test), as.year, sum))


df <- subset(ts_test, (cycle(ts_test) == 7 | cycle(ts_test) == 8))
JulAugsum <- as.ts(aggregate(as.zoo(df), as.year, sum))
```

Comment: Since `df` is a `"zoo"` object, not a `"data.frame"`, you might want to give it a different name, e.g. `z78`,  The second arg to `subset` could be written `cycle(ts_test) %in% 7:8` .

Comment: This would also work but is less general since it won't necessarily work if `sum` is replaced with some other function:     `is78 <- cycle(ts_test) %in% 7:8; as.ts(aggregate(is78 * ts_test, as.year, sum))`

Comment: This points in the right direction, however this might cause problems if a e.g. the first year of the time series starts later than August. Then the output of `JulAugsum` is shorter (and thus not of the same shape as `yearsum`). `z_test <-  as.zoo(ts(rnorm(200), start=c(1922,9), frequency=12));
as.year <- function(x) as.numeric(floor(as.yearmon(x)));
yearsum <- as.ts(aggregate(z_test, as.year, sum));
z_2 <- subset(z_test, (cycle(z_test) == 7 | cycle(z_test) == 8));
JulAugsum <- as.ts(aggregate(z_2, as.year, sum))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck ...your approach provides a result that is of the same length/shape as `yearsum`. However, if there are no data for e.g. July (=NA) then the sum will be still 0 instead of NA?

Comment: `aggregate(is78 * na.fill(ts_test, 0), as.year, sum)` replaces NAs with 0 and then sums.

Comment: do you think I should delete my answer?